# Geom_smooth line not showing up on one of the panels in facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hoping to get some insight on this ... currently creating some plots with ggplot and using facets, as well as adding fits using geom_smooth. I have two fits, a non-linear and linear.

For some reason, the non-linear one is not showing up not the top facet ... it used to work for me and now has stopped!

Here is the graph code:

```
ggplot(example_data, aes(x,y))+
  geom_point(col="black", size=3)+
  facet_grid(k~loc,labeller = as_labeller(loc.labels))+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y~x,col="blue", se=FALSE)+
  geom_smooth(method = "nls", formula = y~A*x^ B, se=FALSE,col="red")
```

This is the output I get:

[image]

and or some reason the red line is missing from the top panel ..

Comment: Hi lwhite, can you provide the values of `loc.labels`?

Comment: In the first you have a warning: `Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`: singular gradient`.

Comment: Because loc = k ?

Comment: Thanks @RuiBarradas this error wasn't showing up before... once I supplied start values all seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to specify start values for the non-linear line .. 
updated code:

```
ggplot(example_data, aes(x,y))+
  geom_point(col="black", size=3)+
  facet_grid(k~loc)+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y~x,col="blue", se=FALSE)+
  geom_smooth(method = "nls", formula = y~A*x^ B, se=FALSE,col="red", 
              method.args =list(start=c(A=400,B=0)))
```

Thanks for the speedy help!